# Python 2.7 - SQL server data retrieve

Tags: python, sql

I am using Python 2.7

Library  pymssql
When retrieving data from the SQL server have this type 'u' line

```
cursor.execute("SELECT param_name FROM Table_2")
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Prints:
(u'Line 1',)
(u'Line 2',)
(u'Line 3',)

How to have the simple string?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
print("ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row[0], row[1]))
```

or access it like dictionary:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT param_name FROM Table_2")
for row in cursor:
    print("ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row['id'], row['name']))
```

There are more useful examples [here](http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html). 
Hope that helps.